# Visits per Isoweek in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to pull visits per isoweek from big query.
however I am failing with the date transformation.
Could you support?

```
StandardSQL
SELECT count  (visitid) as Sessions, date,
EXTRACT (ISOYEAR FROM date) AS isoyear
FROM `xxx_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '201806020' AND '20180630'
GROUP BY date
order by date DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried a query like this?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM date) as yyyy,
       EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM DATE) as ww,
       COUNT(*) as Sessions
FROM `xxx_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '201806020' AND '20180630'
GROUP BY yyyy, ww
ORDER BY MIN(date) DESC;
```